# How to schedule Jenkins to build periodically

Tags: jenkins, build, timer, automation, schedule

I am trying to schedule a jenkins job (timer) to start my Azure VMs back up on the third sunday of every month at 6AM.

I haven't been able to find any resource on this.

Comment: You can used a Build Trigger: https://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-job-schedule.  Sounds like you want to Build Periodically.

Answer (score 0):

From ***Configure job***, You can use ***Build Periodically*** option 
 under ***Build Trigger*** section and in the Schedule text field add the expression: `0 0 1 * *`

The above expression will schedule a build of the job to run on 1st day of every month. For example, Would last have run at Monday, October 1, 2018 12:00:55 AM EDT; would next run at Thursday, November 1, 2018 12:00:55 AM EDT and so on. To create your own cron based upon your requirement you can use https://crontab.guru/.